# Python: Sorting directory under directory based on modified time

Tags: python

I want to iterate directories based on modified time,

Under this path 'C:\Users\smith\AppData\Local\Temp', I have many directories in same name 'scoped_dir' now I want to access the 'scoped_dir' which is the latest one,

```
import os
import time
import glob
file_path = 'C:/Users/smith/AppData/Local/Temp'
for root, dir, files in os.walk(file_path, topdown=True):
 if 'scoped_dir' in root:
    print("root :" + str(root))
    print("dir :" + str(dir))
    print("files :" + str(files))
```

Using the above mentioned code I can access all the directories with name 'scoped_dir', But I want to iterate it based on last modified first, can anyone help me in this.

Comment: os.walk returns a generator, so modification timestamps won't be known upfront I think. if you don't have a ton of dirs/files in your file_path, you could cast the return value of os.walk to a list and e.g. sort the tuples therein by os.path.getmtime.

Answer (score 0):

This builds a list of (dir, modification_time) tuples. Then sorts the list in reversed order of modification time and as a demo prints in some readable format.
Be careful however, if 'scoped_dir' happens to be a substring of a directory, it also will be included, so theoretically you may end up with  more directories than you need.

```
import glob, os, time

dirs = []
for root, dir, files in os.walk(file_path):
    if 'scoped_dir' in root:
        dirs.append((root, os.path.getmtime(root)))

dirs = sorted(dirs, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

for dir, tm in dirs:  # iteration based on last modified first
    print(dir, time.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M', time.gmtime(tm)))
```